# How do I click a div span img using Selenium java

Tags: java, html, selenium, alt

How do I click this image inside a div and span using selenium webdriver (java)?
This is the HTML code:

```
<div id="pane_" name="pane_" xmlns:fo="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Format">
 <ul class="menuMargin">
  <li class="clsHasKids">
   <span onclick="ProcessMouseClick(event)" onkeypress="ProcessKeyPress(event)">
   <img tabindex="0" id="imgError" src="../plaf/images/default/menu/menu_right.gif" alt="Customer">Customer
  </span>
```

This what the xpath is for the "Customer" image link:

```
//*[@id="pane_"]/ul[2]/li/span
```

Some of the codes I used and nothing worked:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Customer")).sendKeys(Keys.SHIFT,Keys.ENTER);


driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[@alt='Customer']")).click();


driver.findElement(By.tagName("//div[@id='pane_']//ul[2]//li//span")).click();
```

Comment: Can you share the link of website where you are performing this?

Comment: Did u tried that Xpath u have mentioned above. Like ** driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="pane_"]/ul[2]/li/span")).click(); **

Comment: Did you try: `driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id="pane_"]/ul[2]/li/span")).click();`?

Comment: @sandeep-kumar @ferenus Tried the above commands and nothing happens. I get this error: `_no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//*[@id='pane_']/ul[2]/li/span"}_`

Comment: @kishan-patel It is our secure site so unable to provide the whole HTML

Comment: There can be many cases as the xpath which you are using might be locating more than one element or some visibility problem.. Can't help without website. Sorry @ebanster

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should try with below `xpath` :-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(. , 'Customer')]")).click();
```

**Edited** :-

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement el = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//span[contains(. , 'Customer')]")));
```

Hope it helps..:)

Comment: nothing happens and I get this error: `Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(. , 'Customer')]"}`

Comment: error as per below:  `Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.TimeoutException: Timed out after 10 seconds waiting for visibility of element located by By.xpath: //span[contains(. , 'Customer')]  
...Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//span[contains(. , 'Customer')]"}`

Comment: @ebanster make sure this element is not inside any frame or iframe??

Comment: Hi @saurabh-gaur apologies for being a noob but I am unable to locate frame or iframe from the HTML code. Does this mean it is not inside?

Comment: @ebanster you need to verify it on browser console just paste `document.getElementByTagName('frame')` and `document.getElementByTagName('iframe')`..and let me know the result

Comment: how do i define this `document.getElementByTagName('frame')` as it says "Invalid character constant"

Comment: @ebanster it is `document.getElementsByTagName('frame')`...leaved `s` by mistake..and you need to execute this browser console by pressing f12 at that page where you want to locate element...

Comment: Hi mate, apologies for the late response. Got sidetracked with another project. Anyway, I verified it on the browser console, the below appeared for that particular frame: `<frame id="MENUSECTION000413695702" name="MENUSECTION000413695702" scrolling="auto" src="../jsps/genrequest.jsp?&amp;routineName=OS.NEW.USER&amp;routineArgs=MENU&amp;skin=default&amp;compId=AU0010001&amp;usrRole=&amp;compScreen=COMPOSITE.SCREEN_ROSALE_000413695704&amp;contextRoot=&amp;windowName=MENUSECTION000413695702&amp;user=ROSALE&amp;WS_replaceAll=&amp;WS_parentComposite=">`

Comment: @ebanster ok that means there is a frame, so you need to swith that framebefore finding element as `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("frame[src*='genrequest.jsp']")));` or `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.frameToBeAvailableAndSwitchToIt(By.cssSelector("frame[id*='MENUSECTION']")));`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click on the span to call the javascript onclick event this will do

```
WebElement e = d.findElement(By.id("pane_"));

e.findElement(By.tagName("span")).click();
```

and for clicking on image

```
e.findElement(By.tagName("span")).findElement(By.tagName("img")).click();
```

Comment: Same as the aboves and nothing happens unfortunately. Error `no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"pane_"}`

Comment: add a explicit wait 

WebDriverWait.until(condition-that-finds-the-element);